# How can I create route URL for views in core PHP?

Tags: php

I am creating an application that contains my views in something like *views/index.php* or *views/auth/login.php* and the URL on the web something like

*http://localhost/app/views/auth/login.php*

In simple words I want to create a route for my above URL is **http://localhost/app/login**

Any solution for creating a route in core PHP

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Please edit.

Comment: @Progrock please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to use clean (SEO) links instead of calling directly php scripts. Solution depends on web server you are using.

For apache (one of the most used ones) you must make redirection from your "imaginary" paths (i.e. /app/login) to your real script, which will handle the request.
Again, most used solution for apache is to add your redirection rules in .htaccess file. From there apache server will read your rule for every request to your server and if conditions are met redirection will be made.

There are many tutorials on how to do that, i.e.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pbAV6AU99I

Or: https://moz.com/blog/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls

Answer (score 2):

Use .htaccess file , to rewrite the url.
You could refer https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize [UrlRewriting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) (I assume you are using Apache, for other Webservers this is similar).

Then, you can rewrite all calls to a dedicated PHP file that handles the requests and `includes` the file.

In your Webserver vHost configuration or the .htaccess file, you'll need something like

```
<Directory /path/to/webroot>
    AllowOverride None
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  redirect.php [L]
</Directory>
```

This will redirect every request that does not address an actual file to redirect.php

In redirect.php

```php
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$path = str_replace($url, "http://localhost/", ""); // There are more beautiful ways for this

/* $path should now state "app/login" from your example. 
Either you provide a manual mapping or change your request to 
include the auth part (so request path matches file path). Then e.g.:*/

$file = "views/" . $path . ".php";
if (file_exists($file)) {
    require($file);
} else {
    // Display 404
}
```

This is a basic example without GET parameters, anchors and security checks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called .htaccess in your application. Inside the file add rewrite rules like this 

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [NC,L]`

I used this code to redirect from "/login.php" to "/login"